# Gmail - Download CSV = mangled file

Tags: javascript, csv, email, gmail

I attach a csv file to an email and send to a gmail account. Go to ANY browser and open gmail app and look at the CSV or download it - Google has inserted extra carriage returns and another mysterious character in front of each row that Text Wrangler interprets as an upside-down question mark...What's happening here, what's the character, and how to strip it in javascript?

Another note - in Mac Mail program using same GMail account - I can grab the same csv file - and it's fine.

Happens on both Mac and Windows 10. ( so far )

Thanks.

Comment: More relevant here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/